# Algebraic Dual / Continuous Dual

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space, let $E^{\ast}$ denote
its continuous (i.e., Banach space) dual, and let $E'$ be its algebraic
dual. Clearly, $E^{\ast}$ is a proper vector subspace of $E'$. Now, let
us suppose that $E^{\ast}$ and $E'$ are algebraically isomorphic (i.e.,
as vector spaces). Does it follow that $E$ contains an isomorph of
the Banach space $\ell_{1}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

[By "*isomorph
of *X*" I mean a closed linear subspace both algebraically
and topologically isomorphic to *X*.]

P.S. This is under ZFC + CH.

P.P.S. The answer is affirmative if $E$ is the dual of a separable [infinite-dimensional] Banach space. It would be interesting to see if it is also affirmative when $E$ is a "nice" space. For instant, a Banach *lattice*.

Comment: (If the subspace is topologically isomorphic, it will be algebraically isomorphic, no?)

Comment: Well, that's the definition, isn't it ? When you are saying that two normed spaces are isomorphic, are you omitting the linearity ? :-)

Comment: I'm just wondering why you phrased the definition ion your last sentence in the way you did: how could the subspace be topologically isomorphic and not algebraically isomorphic?

Comment: I'm no Banachist, but the hypothesis that the algebraic and topological duals have the same dimension seems very unlikely to me.  (At the very least, this cannot happen for a reflexive space.)  Do you know an example of an infinite-dimensional Banach space with this property?

Comment: But I didn't say they could have different algebraic dimensions, yet being homeomorphic. Still, this is the canonical definition.


Comment: @Mariano By "topologically isomorphic" I mean "homeomorphic" only.


Comment: I'm seconding Pete's comment/question. Could you please give an example of an infinite-dimensional Banach space $E$ for which the algebraic and continuous dual spaces are isomorphic as vector spaces? If not, then I think you need to open a separate question to address this...

Comment: Ady had replied, in part, "@Yemon E = the space of all bounded sequences. Or, E = the dual of C[0,1]." I've taken the liberty of deleting the rest of the comment, and the ensuing conversation. Please complain on meta :-)

Comment: I think that in order to test our intuition on this problem we should look at James tree spaces. A tree is a partial order set $(T,<)$ such that for every $t$ in $T$ the set $\{ s\in T: s<t\}$ equiped with the relation $<$ is well-ordered. For every tree $T$ the corresponding James tree space $JT$ is hereditarily $\ell_2$ (in particular, it does not contain a copy of $\ell_1$). Now there are many special trees (Kurepa, Souslin etc). Why for EVERY tree $T$ the cardinality of its topological dual $JT^*$ is strictly less than the cardinality of its algebraic dual $JT'$? I just cannot see. 

Comment: Why CH        ?

Comment: @Jonas Just to avoid "pathological" sets. Since I'm not believe in them. And because this is a FA question, and I'm liking CH.

Comment: I can't see doing anything in FA without CH.

Comment: @Harry: it depend what you mean by "anything" -- or, I suppose, what you mean by FA :)

Answer (score 10):

Ok Ady, since you like CH I will work with CH, and to make your life
easier, I will work with GCH.

Since I do not expect that everybody in MO is aware of various
Banach space constructions, let me give some information on James
tree spaces which are relevant to the question.

A *tree* is a partially order set $(T,<)$ such that for every $t$ in $T$ the
initial segment $\{s\in T: s < t\}$ is well-ordered under $ < $.
A segment of $T$ is a subset $S$ of $T$ which is:

1. linearly ordered under $ < $ and
2. for all $s, t, w\in T$ if $s < t < w$ and $s, w \in S$ then $t\in S$.

The *completion* of $T$, usually denoted by $c(T)$, is the collection of all initial
segments of $T$ ordered by inclusion. Notice that $c(T)$ contains $T$ and
is much larger than $T$. For instance, if $T$ is the tree of all finite sequences
of natural numbers (usually called the Baire tree, which is clearly countable),
then its completion is the Baire-tree together with its branches (i.e. the
Baire space) and so it has the cardinality of the continuum.

For every tree $T$ the corresponding James tree space $JT$ is defined to
be the completion of $c_{00}(T)$ with the norm:
$$\|v\| = \sup\{ (\sum_{i=1}^d (\sum_{t\in S_i} v(t) )^2 )^{1/2} \}$$
where the above supremum is taken over all finite families $(S_i)_{i=1}^d$ of
pairwise disjoint segments of $T$. Basic facts (I can provide appropriate
references to anyone who is interested):

- For every tree $T$ the space $JT$ is hereditarily $\ell_2$; that is,
  every infinite-dimensional subspace of $JT$ contains a copy of $\ell_2$.
- For every tree $T$ the second dual of $JT$ is linearly isometric to
  the James tree space of the completion $c(T)$ of $T$. In particular,
  neither $JT^* $ nor $JT^{**}$ contain a copy of $\ell_1$.

Now we come to the specifics of the construction. Remember that we work
with GCH. This implies, in particular, the following: if $X$ is a Banach
space of cardinality $\kappa$, then the algebraic dual of $X$ has cardinality
$\kappa^+$.

Let $T$ be the tree of all countable subsets of $\omega_1$ equipped
with the partial order of end-extension. We have GCH, hence, the tree
is just all sequences of real numbers, and so, it has cardinality
$\aleph_1$. The cardinality of the corresponding James tree space is
also $\aleph_1$.

The completion $c(T)$ of our tree $T$ is the set of all subsets of
$\omega_1$. Hence it has cardinality $2^{\aleph_1}$ which is,
under GCH, $\aleph_2$. It follows that the cardinality of $JT^{**}$
is $\aleph_2$.

Now consider cases.

Case 1: the topological dual $JT^* $ of $JT$ has cardinality strictly
bigger than $\aleph_1$. Then we are done: our counterexample is $JT$.

Case 2: the topological dual $JT^* $ of $JT$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$.
We are also done: our counterexample is $JT^* $.

Comment: $\kappa^+$ stands for what again?  Successor?

Comment: $kappa^+$ is the successor of $\kappa$; it is standard set-theoretic notation. Sorry for not explaining in the main text.

Comment: Very nice, Pandelis! I'm making some editing (in order to make your life harder ;-)).

Comment: Nice. The argument is a very complicated variation of the example at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10993/can-you-prove-equivalence-without-being-able-to-calculate-it/11217#11217 :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can look at $\ell_2(\gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is an uncountable set. The topological dual is itself. Its algebraic dual seems to have the same cardinality as $\ell_2(\gamma)$.

Comment: It is not hard to see that $\left|\ell_{2}\left(\gamma\right)\right|=\left|\gamma\right|$ in
this case. OTOH, any mapping from $\gamma$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can be
"extended'' to a linear (discontinuous) functional, so that $2^{\left|\gamma\right|}$ would be
the dimension of the algebraic dual.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cardinality of *E'* should always be greater than the cardinality of $E^*$, so they never will be isomorphic in any sense. Basically, as pointed out [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-it/13372#13372), $E^*$ is the space of all maps from a topological basis of *E* into a field. *E'* is analogously the space of all maps from an algebraic basis to a field. So, this boils down to the question:

> In an infinite-dimensional Banach space, does an algebraic basis ever have the same cardinality as a topological basis?

I think the answer is no. For example, in $l^2$ (which is the smallest infinite-dimensional Banach space), the topological basis is countable. As Ady points out, the algebraic basis should have cardinality $2^{|\mathbb N|}$.

I'll community wiki this because this is a guess rather than a proof. Feel free to edit & improve. I seem to remember I knew a slick proof of Ady's statement; if I actually remember it, I'll put it in.

Comment: (1)What about the examples Ady gives in the comments above?  (2)What in general do you mean by topological basis?  For Hilbert space I assume you mean orthonormal basis, and more generally some Banach spaces have Schauder bases, but I don't know if an analogous set exists in every Banach space.  (3) Your characterization of the topological dual isn't accurate; you can't send the "topological basis" just anywhere.  E.g., consider the identification of the dual of $l^2$ with $l^2$.  (This point, however, only shows that the topological dual is "smaller" than you indicated.)

Comment: Oh, in case it is confusing, the examples Ady gave are now in the comment by Scott Morrison, $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ and $C[0,1]^*$.

Comment: FWIW not every Banach space has a Schauder basis. If memory serves rightly, the first counter-example was due to Per Enflo. That said, the gap between Schauder basis and Hamel basis is *vast* in infinite dimensions